# Problema con array_diff

Tags: php

Estoy teniendo problemas con la función array_diff_assoc de php, me da el error

> "**Notice**:  Array to string conversion in "

El código es el siguiente:

```
static public function ctrMostrarConceptosLiquidarDistintos($item, $valor, $datos){

    $tabla = "Concepto";

    $listaConceptos = json_decode($datos, true);

    $nuevaLista = array();

    $nuevosValores = array();

    foreach ($listaConceptos as $key => $value) {

        if ($value["Fijo"] == "N") {

            $dtConceptos = array("ConceptoID" => $value["ConceptoID"],
                                "Descripcion" => $value["Descripcion"]);

            array_push($nuevaLista, $dtConceptos);
        }
    }

    $traerConceptos = ModeloPayment::mdlMostrarConceptosLiquidar($tabla, $item, $valor);

    foreach ($traerConceptos as $key2 => $value2) {

        $dtConceptos = array("ConceptoID" => $value2["ConceptoID"],
                             "Descripcion" => $value2["Descripcion"]);

        array_push($nuevosValores, $dtConceptos);
    }

    $felec = array_diff_assoc($nuevosValores, $nuevaLista);

    return $felec;
}
```

Cuando el array $listaConceptos esta vació, la función array_diff_assoc funciona y me devuelve un array, pero cuando el array $listaConceptos tiene un valor me da ese error, que podría estar mal?

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que estás trabajando con arrays multidimensionales (los elementos de tus arrays son también arrays), pero `array_diff_assoc` solo funciona con arrays unidimensionales (o una dimensión en arrays multidimensionales) como se especifica en una [nota de la documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php):

> Esta función sólo comprueba una dimensión de un array n-dimensional. Por supuesto, se pueden comprobar arrays de más dimensiones usando, por ejemplo, `array_diff_assoc($array1[0], $array2[0]);`.

En la misma página, los usuarios ofrecen diferentes funciones para solucionar este problema y que se comparen todas las dimensiones y no sólo una (la idea básica en la que se basan es tener un bucle que ejecuta la función para cada dimensión).

Dejo aquí la de [Giosh](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-diff-assoc.php#111675), que es la versión más votada:

```
<?php
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2) {
  $difference=array();
  foreach($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if( is_array($value) ) {
      if( !isset($array2[$key]) || !is_array($array2[$key]) ) {
        $difference[$key] = $value;
      } else {
        $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
        if( !empty($new_diff) )
          $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
      }
    } else if( !array_key_exists($key,$array2) || $array2[$key] !== $value ) {
      $difference[$key] = $value;
    }
  }
  return $difference;
}
?>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Desarrolle esta función que creo que cumple el criterio pedido, es dentro de todo óptima y se puede implementar genéricamente.

```
<?php
$array1 = [array("id" => 1, "nombre" => "Juan", "apellido"=>"Ramirez"), 
array("id" => 2, "nombre" => "Micaela", "apellido"=>"Rodriguez"),
array("id" => 3, "nombre" => "Pedro", "apellido"=>"Martinez"),
array("id" => 4, "nombre" => "Ernesto", "apellido"=>"Perez")];

$array2 = [array("id" => 9, "nombre" => "Carlos", "apellido"=>"Suarez"), 
array("id" => 2, "nombre" => "Micaela", "apellido"=>"Rodriguez"),
array("id" => 5, "nombre" => "Agustin", "apellido"=>"Reinos"),
array("id" => 4, "nombre" => "Ernesto", "apellido"=>"Perez")];

$resultado = array_diff_multi($array1, $array2, "comparator_default");

print_r($resultado);

function array_diff_multi($a1, $a2, $comparator)
{
    if(!is_array($a1) ||!is_array($a2))
        return $a1;
    $retorno = Array();
    $existe = 0;
    foreach($a1 as $element)
    {
        $existe = 0;
        foreach($a2 as $element2)
        {
            if($comparator($element, $element2))
            {
                $existe = 1;
                break; // Detengo la ejecucion al encontrar al menos una coincidencia.
            }
        }
        if($existe == 0)
            array_push($retorno, $element);
    }
    return $retorno;
}

function comparator_default($a, $b)
{
    if(!is_array($a) || !is_array($b))
        return FALSE;
    if(!isset($a['id']) || !isset($a['nombre']) || !isset($a['apellido']))
        return FALSE;
    if(!isset($b['id']) || !isset($b['nombre']) || !isset($b['apellido']))
        return FALSE;
    if($a['id'] == $b['id'])
        if($a['nombre'] == $b['nombre'])
            if($a['apellido'] == $b['apellido'])
                return TRUE;
    return FALSE;
}
?>
```

La probé solo con el lote del ejemplo, pero creo que debería funcionar para cualquier tipo de array.
Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme!